# Appropriate database for literature research

Tags: xml, database, indexing, lucene, full-text-search

I am working on a research system that is used to find documents from a large library (~10th of millions) of texts. Their current source format is XML. This reserach is done by searching for keywords in the main text body/title/abstract as well as narrowing the scope by filtering with the help of meta information. The documents each have information about things like their publishing date, author, serial number, topic/genre, country of origin. A typical user might include several of these search criteria to narrow down their research to a small subset (a couple hundred hits) by combining the search terms with operators like AND, OR, NOT or is-followed-by.

As far as I see, the following system criteria result from this:

- build to handle read heavy loads
- comparatively few writes (occasional additions of new documents as the library is steadily growing. Very few edits of existing documents. None of that is done by users, but rather by admins)
- supporting full text search (considering lucene, elasticsearch, solr here)
- handling the use of several index fields and complex, varied search queries. These queries are  not pre-defined.
- quick response time, as users might iterate through several search queries before they settle on a result list.

I've done some basic research on databases to familiarize myself with the field and terminology.  I got a suggestion to check out Cassandra, as it is considered a very fast database system and took a closer look on how it works and how a full text index could be incorporated into it. But in the end it doesn't seems to be the right fit. (feel free to correct me if you think I'm wrong on that one.)

The database landscape is vast and varied. It's tempting to pick one of the popular big names you see mentioned often, but that does not mean they are the right fit. So what I'm hoping for are suggestions on specific database systems I could take a look at next that would fit the description above. :)

Comment: This question is probably too opinion-based for Stack Overflow. You may have more success asking on [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Check if there are any relevant answers first, of course. Or maybe try [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). I am not too familiar with those sites, so browse them first, before posting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll make sure to do that too.